# Unable to fetch individually gzip chunks with HttpComponents-HttpClient 4.3

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am attempting to fetch data from a server sending individually gzipped chunks using HttpClient 4.3 but the HttpEntity content only seems to contain the decoded value of the first chunk. How can I get the subsequent chunks uncompressed or not?

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
final HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url.toString());
method.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
return response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: What is the runtime type of the returned entity?

Comment: org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity

Comment: Can you give an example of the server sending gzipped chunks?

Comment: Curl Trace -> https://gist.github.com/huhlig/51b03acc0a9923b78bea 
Each block is a new GZip Block